# Check whether an element exists in mvc formcollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formcollection

I am receiving some data in mvc controller as FormCollection. I would like to check if there is a particular key exists in the formcollection.

```
 public JsonResult FullRetailerUpdate(FormCollection data)
 {
     //I want to check if 
     //data["AnElement"] is exist
 }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using `.Contains()`:-

```
 public JsonResult FullRetailerUpdate(FormCollection data)
 {
    if (data.AllKeys.Contains("AnElement")) 
    {
      // Your Stuff
    }
    else
    {
      // Your Stuff
    }   
 }
```

Comment: contains no more exist in Allkeys now.

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question was about `FormCollection` but for those using `IFormCollection` here is the solution.

```
public IActionResult GetProjectDelivery(IFormCollection data)
{
    if (data.ContainsKey("AnElement"))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    else
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```